# Error 404 creating a view in mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am linking a SQL database to my MVC ASP.Net.  I have created the model, context class, web config and controller.
However for some reason when I create a view by right clicking on the 'views' folder I get a 404 error when I debug.  If I create my view by right clicking next to:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
```

in the Controller class i don't get this error.  Is there any reason for this?

Comment: Are you creating the view in Views or in Views/{Controller}/  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it seems like you might be creating the View in the wrong folder.
When you add a view for a Controller/Action, you must create subdirectory in ~/Views that matches your controller's name.

For example,

```
public ProductController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

You would add your Index.cshtml to Views/Product:

```
~/Views/Product/Index.cshtml
```

If you wanted to return another view called "Other.cshtml",

```
        return View("Other");
```